# Why are there two switches to enable demo mode?

Tags: stock-android

In System UI Tuner -> Demo mode, there are two toggles, "enable demo mode" and "show demo mode". "Show demo mode" does nothing when "enable demo mode" isn't enabled, so why have two buttons to enable demo mode?

Comment: Which Android device and version is it?

Comment: @Firelord Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1 MMB29Q.

Comment: https://www.protechtraining.com/blog/post/880